# Cant see our build in iTunes connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

We have uploaded a new build using `Xcode 6` , and the submission was successful .
In `Itunes connect` in the app page, we filled everything, and we have to chose the build, but there is no `plus` button (as usual) to upload the build,only says `"upload your build using Xcode 5.1"`

I know sometimes you have to wait, we waited an hour, and even tried again, without success.
We also have the same issue with an update of an app (one is new,one is an update)

Is there a way to do something to see it ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the version number of your app, reupload the build but in the upload process uncheck "Include app symbols for your application to receive symbolicated crash logs from Apple". The build should appear under "Betas" and then you have to approve it as a normal build. Once you do that, it should appear on the app's page.